# Powering on my windows 10 desktop PC blocks internet on Wifi devices

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a peculiar issue with wifi internet here. I have Mi Wifi Router 3 with 2 different SSIDs for 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz bands. I have around 5 to 6 mobile devices, 1 Mi Android TV  connected via Wifi. One Windows 10 desktop PC connected to router via Lan cable.

When I turn on my desktop PC, randomly my wifi on 2.4Ghz devices gets stuck and devices show no internet connection. When tried to disconnect and reconnect to the 2.4Ghz wifi, the devices don't connect to the same network which was working earlier. This happens pretty frequently, but not all the time. Note that wifi on 5Ghz still works normally!!!

I tried restarting the router and many things. But shutting down my PC has fixed the issue instantly! Whenever I start my PC, these disruptions will start to occur again and again.

I verified that there are no static IPs defined to any devices on the network and all the IPs are set to DHCP.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the desktop _have_ Wi-Fi (even if you use wired ethernet)? Does it have Bluetooth? Does it have a wireless mouse/keyboard? Does it have some kind of wireless audio system (e.g. headphones)? All these things often share the same 2.4 GHz band.

Comment: Does the problem occur if you don't connect the Ethernet cable? Does the problem occur if you power on the computer but don't boot Windows (e.g. if you open the BIOS settings screen, or if you boot a Linux USB stick)?

Comment: @grawity No, desktop don't have wifi. I have wireless(non bluetooth) keyboard connected to my PC. This looks to be a valid point. When I face the issue, I'll unplug the wireless keyboard dongle and validate.

Comment: @grawity replaced my wireless keyboard with a wired one. Switched off wifi extender which extends my 2.4GHz wifi. But still problem isn't solved. Can a bad ethernet card on my pc cause this issue? I'm clueless